# How to make sticky header table in bootstrap vue

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm new to using javascript and vuejs technology, and I have case like this
I've using table components from BootstrapVue like this :

```
<b-table
   style="white-space: nowrap;"
   v-else
   bordered
   hover
   responsive
   class="position-relative mb-0"
   :per-page="perPage"
   :current-page="currentPage"
   :items="items"
   :fields="fields"
   :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
   :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
   :sort-direction="sortDirection"
   :filter="filter"
   @filtered="onFiltered"
   >
</b-table>
```

And I've tried `sticky-header` but I don't think it's suitable, because what I expect is a sticky header without any restrictions on scrolling inside the table, but scrolling outside the table/body and with the addition of a sticky header table when it reaches the top.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sticky-vuetify-table-header-3o0km?file=/pages/index.vue:1240-1283

That is an example I want to do on my page, but I'm struggling and can't find an answer for the Bootstrap Vue framework.
How do I style my table so that it looks like the example above?

Comment: You already provided a working example with source code.. so why not use their approach? For example adding a `sticky-header` class and applying the CSS for it.

Comment: I've tried to find a way to outsmart this with CSS, but I still haven't found it until now. That's why I'm asking here

Comment: Okay so maybe you can create a codesandbox, jsfiddle or CodePen of your own to demonstrate your code?